# Number based on Adjacent nodes

Tags: math, graph, equation

Let's assume I have a directed graph with 5 nodes and 6 edges:

```
1,2
2,3
4,3
2,4
4,1
5,4
```

Is there a way to generate a unique number to each of the edges(between 1 and `|E|`) combining the numbers of its adjacent nodes?

For example, for edge <4,3> if we can assign this edge with the absolute difference 2. But this way the numbering won't be unique.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I found what is known as a [pairing function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pairing_function#Cantor_pairing_function) which generates a unique number.But it doesn't ensure its between 1 and `|E|`

Answer (score 1):

If `|E|` = 6 and the unique id must be between 1 and `|E|`, that means there can only be 6 unique ids.


It wouldn't be possible to have a unique id for every edge because there is way more than `|E|` combinations of edge verticie pairs in a directed graph. So you wouldnt be able to use integers.


One approach would be to take the fraction of the nodes. The fractions would range from 1/5 to 5. add 1 to your fraction and now you are between 6/5 and 6. Im not sure if the id need to be integers.

You could also have one number as a the ones place and the other as the tenths place. TLDR: if your using floats or doubles you have lots of options for unique ids otherwise you have none.